# Symfony render controller and bootstrap tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, tabs, twig

I have 3 tabs in my app and I need for each one of them to render the specific controller.
The problem is, it works fine for the first tab, but not so much after I start navigating.
Basically, pretty much everything that has been loaded on the page stays on the page. So if I click on the second tab, it adds up to the content of the first tab. When I go back to the first one, it stays the same.
My tabs work just fine with plain text, so I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong when rendering the controllers.
Can any of you shed some light on this?

```
<div class="row">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs col-lg-12" id="myTabs" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item col-lg-3">                       
            <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#bouteille" role="tab" aria-controls="bouteille" aria-selected="true">Bouteille</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item col-lg-3">
             <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#membre" role="tab" aria-controls="membre" aria-selected="false">Membre</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item col-lg-3">
             <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#pointDeVente" role="tab" aria-controls="pointDeVente" aria-selected="false">Point de vente</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
      <div class="tab-content col-lg-12" id="myTabContent">                   
          <div class="tab-pane active" id="bouteille" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="bouteille-tab">
               {% block flashBag %}
                   {% for message in app.session.flashbag.get("info") %}
                       <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable fade show " role="alert" class="col-lg-12">
                                {{ message }}
                        </div>    
                   {% endfor %}
               {% endblock flashBag %}
               {{ render(controller("App\\Controller\\BouteilleController::formulaireRechercherBouteillesAction")) }}

            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="membre" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="membre-tab">
                {{ render(controller("App\\Controller\\MembreController::formulaireRechercherMembresAction")) }}
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pointDeVente" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pointDeVente-tab">
                   {{ render(controller("App\\Controller\\PointDeVenteController::formulaireRechercherPointDeVenteAction")) }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks,
Emma

Comment: Why not just include templates with the code you need directly instead of using different controller actions to render the template?

Comment: This looks like a javascript / bootstrap markup error, rather than a Symfony controller render error. Can you post the nav tabs code that should be on top of this snippet ?

Comment: @ChipDean because I need the data from the controller in the view I would include...

Comment: @FlorentDestremau I added the nav tabs code in the main post. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the same problem if you put plain text instead of `{{ render(controller) }}` text ?

Like "Bouteille", "Membre" and "Point de vente". If you still experience this, then you should look closer to the bootstrap markup and adjust accordingly. If this still doesn't work, maybe the bootstrap javascript is not loaded correctly on the page

Comment: I works just fine with plain text... I go from a tab to another and only see what I'm supposed to see...